# No message received from Android GCM

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I am trying to send a notification using GCM. The registration in GoogleCloudMessaging part is working fine and it generate Reg. ID like `APA91bFZCccJh2Yt-r-9WSHk0FvmkzxCjhK9xsG2Ggc-jXNmdIg0g9Su3k5-KSL9wVd-_5CiOuqy8FKE4y7i_E6APqKsU4yTlTLmoX2pTQK25rj8JNHXcXGrd-sLDoec8GZ6jxOgtnZenzjj51eDRZMoCU_UNd1UnA`

I used this ID and send a message to GSM. The response from GCM server is also fine : `{"multicast_id":7600934834361287625,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1401367637744857%f2c63832f9fd7ecd"}]}`

But no message received in my application end, not even the WakefulBroadcastReceiver is called. Here is the code in App end:

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gcmtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcmtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gcmtest.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gcmtest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gcmtest.ShowActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.example.gcmtest.GCMNotificationIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.gcmtest.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.gcmtest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
  public class RegisterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        Button gcmRegisterButton;
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
        Context context = this;
        String regId = "";

        public static final String REG_ID = "regId";
        private static final String APP_VERSION = "appVersion";

        static final String TAG = "Register Activity";

        private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

            gcmRegisterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gcmRegisterButton);
            gcmRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (regId.isEmpty()) {
                        regId = registerGCM();
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "GCM RegId: " + regId);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Already Registered with GCM Server!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        protected boolean checkPlayService() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                            PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                    finish();
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public String registerGCM() {

            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regId = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regId.isEmpty()) {

                registerInBackground();

                Log.d("RegisterActivity",
                        "registerGCM - successfully registered with GCM server - regId: "
                                + regId);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "RegId already available. RegId: " + regId,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("regId", regId);
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Before starting main activity.");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                Log.d("RegisterActivity", "After finish.");
            }
            return regId;
        }

        private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                    RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String registrationId = prefs.getString(REG_ID, "");
            if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
                return "";
            }
            int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
            if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
                Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
                return "";
            }
            return registrationId;
        }

        private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                        .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
                return packageInfo.versionCode;
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("RegisterActivity",
                        "I never expected this! Going down, going down!" + e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        private void registerInBackground() {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String msg = "";
                    try {
                        if (gcm == null) {
                            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                        }
                        regId = gcm.register(Config.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID);
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "registerInBackground - regId: "
                                + regId);
                        msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

                        storeRegistrationId(context, regId);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Error: " + msg);
                    }
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "AsyncTask completed: " + msg);
                    return msg;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Registered with GCM Server." + msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Registered with GCM Server." + msg);

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(regId)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RegId is empty!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("regId", regId);
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "Before starting main activity.");
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                        Log.d("RegisterActivity", "After finish.");
                    }
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
        }

        private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                    RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
            Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(REG_ID, regId);
            editor.putInt(APP_VERSION, appVersion);
            editor.commit();
        }
......
.....
    }
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("GcmBroadcastReceiver","Broadcast Received.");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

**GCMNotificationIntentService.java**

```
public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("IntentService","IntentService started.");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
             * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
             * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
             * don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                // error in GoogleCloudMessage

            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                // GoogleCloudMessage deleted from server

                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {

                String gcmData = intent.getExtras().getString("data");
                Log.d("gcmData", gcmData);
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ShowActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

What is problem in my code?

Comment: On a first glance I can't see anything wrong. Did you try to send the notification while your app is connected to your PC? You should check the logcat to see if the broadcast receiver is called, and if the service is called.

Comment: I have tested both in device(not connected) and emulator. No, broadcast receiver or service is not called.

Comment: did you solved this...

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using Browser API key to send the message from server (PHP code) to android device.